# How to update published extension through command line in Visual studio market place?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, marketplace

I have published my extension in v1.0 and have to provide update in next week in V2.0.

Shall I update my existing extension to V2.0 through commandline?

I followed below commands for publish my extensions to VSMarket place.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-publishing-a-visual-studio-extension-via-command-line?view=vs-2017

Comment: Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-update-a-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2017#to-publish-an-update-of-an-extension), try using similar step in your first publish.(Make sure the same product ID and higher version number).

Comment: Also, you can sign in the marketplace to publish and update by UI actions. It can be more convenient I think.

Comment: Hi vijay, any update?

Comment: Yes , Updated by UI.

Comment: Glad to know this issue  won't unblock you.